# CLion and CMake error: "Could not find X11"

Tags: c++, cygwin, clion

I originally had clion working perfectly fine and stupidly thought it would be a good idea to switch the compiler over to `msvc` from `cygwin` but now the `glfw` does not working. From what I am able to tell is it thinks its on a mac even though I am on a windows. Note that I have never move or used the project onto a mac (or CLion as a whole) and that this error is after moving back to `cygwin`. The compiler looks fine but the `glfw` package seems to be the one that is now screwed up.

Cmake output

```
C:\Users\Matt\.CLion2017.1\system\cygwin_cmake\bin\cmake.exe -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /cygdrive/c/Users/Matt/CLionProjects/SkyGames
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Could NOT find Vulkan (missing:  VULKAN_LIBRARY VULKAN_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Using X11 for window creation
CMake Error at /cygdrive/c/Users/Matt/.CLion2017.1/system/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.7.1/Modules/FindX11.cmake:429 (message):
  Could not find X11
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  Externals/GLFW3/CMakeLists.txt:212 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/cygdrive/c/Users/Matt/CLionProjects/SkyGames/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(SkyGames)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp Engine/Window.cpp Engine/Window.h Engine/Helpers/functor.h Engine/Engine.cpp Engine/Engine.h Engine/Interfaces/NonCopyable.h Engine/Interfaces/Singleton.h Engine/Interfaces/Manager.h Engine/Observer/Subject.h Engine/Observer/EventListener.cpp Engine/Observer/EventListener.h Engine/Math/EngineMath.cpp Engine/Math/EngineMath.h)
add_executable(SkyGames ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Externals/GLFW3)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
include_directories(SkyGames ${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR} ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(SkyGames glw)
target_link_libraries(SkyGames ${GLFW_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_glu_LIBRARY})
```

I am fairly new to CLion so I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: looks like X11 is not installed or is installed somewhere unusual, you'll need to offer a command line argument to help cmake find it. you'll need to check the docs of the various findOpenGL.cmake etc modules you are referencing with find_package()

Comment: x11 is for unix based systems and I am running windows which is linux based so there wouldn't be x11 installed anywhere and therefore cmake is glitching somewhere. Just not sure where or how to fix the issue.

Comment: I'm assuming the error is coming from inside the find_package(OpenGL) call. You'll need to check the docs on installing opengl on windows. presumably opengl needs a renderer? which is by default x11. However its config script will search for others. you may need to supply command line definitions (-DXXX=YYY) to guide it. You need to consult the docs on these scripts. For example: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindOpenGL.cmake

Comment: okay perfect I will look into that. thanks for the help.